# AngularJS data doesn't refresh until second button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller, datatable

I want to add jQuery datatable using AngularJS.

```
 $scope.SearchData = function () {
        var myData = new Object();
        myData.EmployeeCode = $("#Person").val();


        $http.post("/admin/GetData", myData)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.itemData = response.data.Initiator;
                $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
            });
    };
```

I am using this searching the data. This is working after the second click of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's watchers problem,  use **setTimeout** and  **apply** to fix it:

```
 myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){ // just example

  $timeout(()=>{
     $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
   })
```

or

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
     $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
     $scope.$apply(); //this triggers a $digest
   })
```

Angular has no way of knowing what you might change. In this case it’s your responsibility to call $apply() manually, which triggers a $digest cycle.

Similarly, if you have a directive that sets up a DOM event listener and changes some models inside the handler function, you need to call $apply() to ensure the changes take effect.

Comment: There is no need of setTimeout in that case, and if there was then angular has $timeout service which is better to use.

Comment: @BillP,  you are right, $timeout replace setTimout with $apply

Comment: There's `$setTimeout` in your first snippet instead of `$timeout`